Need help with understanding water filtration pipes
I have a whole house water filtration system installed with valves on each colored line. The intake line is orange, the bypass line is yellow, and the line going into the house is blue.
I have a question about how to activate the bypass mode. I understand that opening the valve on the yellow line activates the bypass mode, but should I also shut the valve on the orange line when in bypass mode?
Additionally, which valves should I adjust when changing the water filter? I plan to shut the orange valve, but what should I do with the yellow and blue valves?
Edit: to clarify, what looks like a valve on the picture is a hose bib. Each line has a ball valve on the side, which is not clearly visible.


which valves should I adjust when changing the water filter? ... the ones that prevent water from flowing through the filter

the picture shows only one valve

Please upload a better picture that shows the valves you are asking about but have provided a picture where they are either invisible or covered by your artwork. As it stands your question is "what should I do with these valves you can't see the actual location of on my pipe layout, so you can't discern how they interact?"
